# while(rs1.next()) not returning any values

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void addPhoneInvoice(String IMEI,String price,String name, 
  String pNumber) throws SQLException {

    con = GetConnection.GetConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String date1 = dateFormat.format(date);

    this.price = Double.parseDouble(price);


    String updatePhn = "DELETE FROM phonestock where IMEI = '"+IMEI+"'";
    int j = stmt.executeUpdate(updatePhn);
    if(j!=0){

    String getDescriptionQuary = "SELECT PhoneName,WarrantyPeriod,YearORMonth FROM      phonestock WHERE IMEI = '"+IMEI+"'";
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(getDescriptionQuary);

    while(rs1.next()){
        this.phoneName = rs1.getString("PhoneName");
        this.warranty = rs1.getInt("WarrantyPeriod");
        this.yearOrMonth = rs1.getString("YearORMonth");
    }   

    String addPhnTemp = "INSERT INTO invoiceTemp(Description,Date,IMEI,Price,Amount,ContactName,ContactNumber,Warranty,YearOrMonth) VALUES ('"+phoneName+"','"+date1+"','"+IMEI+"',"+price+","+price+",'"+name+"','"+pNumber+"',"+warranty+",'"+yearOrMonth+"')";
    String addPhnPer = "INSERT INTO invoicepermanent(Description,Date,IMEI,Price,Amount,ContactName,ContactNumber,Warranty,YearOrMonth) VALUES ('"+phoneName+"','"+date1+"','"+IMEI+"',"+price+","+price+",'"+name+"','"+pNumber+"',"+warranty+",'"+yearOrMonth+"')";

    int i = stmt.executeUpdate(addPhnTemp);
    i = stmt.executeUpdate(addPhnPer);           

    if(i != 0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Success");
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
}
```

}

this shows Success, but `phoneName`, `warranty`, and `yearOrMonth` didn't return from the database.

Comment: Well, how do you know your query actually returns the results you expect?  Did you run it outside of the app?

Comment: you have deleted the records before selecting. Isn't it?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should not write queries like `String updatePhn = "DELETE FROM phonestock where IMEI = '"+IMEI+"'";` it makes the code prone to SQLinjection resulting in unauthorized access to your database, use `preparedstatement` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because executeUpdate returns the number of rows **affected**. If it's greater than 0, nothing was deleted and you're checking the same IMEI, which is gone. Therefore, if you say `System.err.println(rs1.isLast()); it will return true, because there are no rows found by your select statement.

Comment: Now be a good netizen and vote up all the answers that helped?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think these `INSERT` queries executed successfully. `Date` is reserved word for Mysql. Put some quotes around it.

Here is the list of all [Reserved Words in MySQL 5.5.40](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: **TIP** Add *trailing underscore* on all your database names. Example: `date_`. The SQL spec explicitly promises to never use the trailing underscore. So appending it to all your names means you’ll never have to worry about a collision with over a thousand key words and reserved words used by standard SQL and all the various extensions in database systems. See this [partial list of several hundred](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html). More info in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19758863/642706) on another question.

Comment: Whoops, that URL in my comment should be https://www.drupal.org/node/141051. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8339396/642706) discusses various list of reserved words in SQL and the various database implementations.