# how to select some rows of specific date

Tags: java, android, sql, mysqli, android-sqlite

i using sqlite datebase i want to select some rows of specific date.
where i am using e_date as text

CREATE TABLE `expenses` (
    `id`    integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `e_type`    text NOT NULL,
    `e_date`    text NOT NULL,
    `e_amt` text NOT NULL,
    `e_method`  text NOT NULL,
    `desc`  text
);

where i am trying to select using query

select * from expenses where e_date between 31/7/2014 and 15/8/2014;

but its not working help me out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing your dates in an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format such as `yyyy-MM-dd`. Examples for your two dates...

```
2014-07-31
2014-08-15
```

Using that format means you can actually sort alphanumerically and also compare them. If you then change your query to something like the following, it will work...

```
SELECT * from expenses WHERE e_date >= '2014-07-31' AND e_date <= '2014-08-15'
```

EDIT: Thinking about it, if you use the ISO 8601 format you can actually use the SQL BETWEEN operator but you *must* use single quotes to surround the strings.

```
SELECT * from expenses WHERE e_date BETWEEN '2014-07-31' AND '2014-08-15'
```

Also, just a tip - don't use `id` for your first column, use `_id` instead (notice the preceding 'underscore'). Having a column called `_id` is necessary if you use various Android Adapters and AdapterViews.

Comment: Good suggestion on renaming `id`. But I suggest using **a trailing underscore**, `id_`, rather than leading. The SQL spec explicitly promises to never have reserved words with a trailing underscore. Therefore using a trailing underscore on all your SQL names means never having to worry about, or suffer from, collisions with reserved words and keywords. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19758863/642706) for details.

Comment: @BasilBourque : As I mentioned - when using Android Adapter and AdapterView classes the dataset returned by a query when used with a a Cursor *MUST* have a unique column called `_id`. There's even a specific exception which is thrown if it doesn't have a column called `_id`.