# R2DBC Core DatabaseClient.sql replacing column 'key' to '[*]key'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

r2dbc.core.databaseclient.sql replace query that have column name 'key' to '[*]key' and this causes error in the query execution.

```
Mono<Map<String, Object>> first = db.sql("SELECT key FROM table_a");
```

The executed query will be "SELECT [*]key FROM table_a". This will cause error in the application as the query failed.

Anyone having this issue in their project? Any workaround?

Comment: key is reserved word; hence its failing Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71063481/6840615

Comment: Does this answer your question? [H2 database column name "GROUP" is a reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758467/h2-database-column-name-group-is-a-reserved-word)